# Tailoring is a lot harder with these threads

Tags: riddle

> I am a needle you can't unthread,
>
> The mark of Christ upon my head
>
> (or sometimes a slash or hexagram)
>
> driven to fix is where I am.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you are a:

> Screw

I am a needle you can't unthread,

> Screw resembles a needle, but threads are permanent

The mark of Christ upon my head

> Philips head screw has a cross on top

(or sometimes a slash or hexagram)

> Flathead or hex-head screws

driven to fix is where I am.

> Screw is driven to fix things

Tailoring is a lot harder with these threads

> Screw threads can't be used for tailoring